# Is it possible to animate after a window you opened using JavaScript is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm opening a new window, opening the print dialog box when it opens, then closing that window. After the user closes that window, is it possible to run an animation on the original window as a callback of sorts?

Here's what the code block currently looks like

```
saveWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
saveWindow.print();
saveWindow.close();
$("#save_complete").animate({
    top:'200px'
},"slow");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me

```
saveWindow.print();
$.when(saveWindow.close()).then(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#save_complete").animate({
            paddingTop:"200px"
        },2000);
    },1000);
});
```